# How to restart EC2 instance using terraform without destroying them?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am wondering how can we stop and restart the AWS ec2 instance created using terraform. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Terraform is a tool for `building, changing, and versioning infrastructure`safely and efficiently.  so shutdown or restart you can achieve this using local-exec. Terraform will destroy...terraform destroy https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-dynamodb-30-seconds-readtime-4-mint-adil-m/

Comment: That makes sense. Can you give an example to shutdown or restart instances using local-exec?

Comment: Pls look was not able to post as a comment Subbu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you asked, for example, there is a limit on the comment, so posting as the answer using `local-exec`.

I assume that you already configure `aws configure | aws configure --profile test` using aws-cli.

Here is the complete example to reboot an instance, change VPC SG ID, subnet and key name etc

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "us-west-2"
  profile             = "test"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami                         = "ami-0f2176987ee50226e"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  subnet_id                   = "subnet-45454566645"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["sg-45454545454"]
  key_name                    = "mytest-ec2key"
  tags = {
    Name = "Test EC2 Instance"
  }
}
resource "null_resource" "reboo_instance" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    on_failure  = "fail"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command     = <<EOT
        echo -e "\x1B[31m Warning! Restarting instance having id ${aws_instance.ec2.id}.................. \x1B[0m"
        # aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids ${aws_instance.ec2.id} --profile test
        # To stop instance
        aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids ${aws_instance.ec2.id} --profile test
        echo "***************************************Rebooted****************************************************"
     EOT
  }
#   this setting will trigger script every time,change it something needed
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }


}
```

Now Run `terraform apply`

Once created and you want later to reboot or stop just call

`terraform apply -target null_resource.reboo_instance`

See the logs

[image]

Comment: More background info on this strategy here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/terraform-tool/hEESOVOgL_Q

Answer (score 2):

Using remote-exec:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -r 1"
    ]
  }
```

-r 1 is to delay the reboot and prevent remote-exec command exiting with non-zero code.

Comment: in my case it's just writing `Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...` and continue ( and it didn't shut down anything .. ) no log no details no nothing

Answer (score 0):

I have found simpler way to do it.

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
command = "ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
                   someuser@${aws_eip.ec2_public_ip.public_ip} sudo 'shutdown -r'"
}
```