# Destroy resource using the terraform file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am working on a task where where the requirement is to create an RDS instance, run initial sql script on it to create databases and users.
To achieve this, I am planning two step approach

- Create RDS instance

```
    resource "aws_db_instance" "my_db" {
    #details
    }
```

- Launch an EC2 instance and execute SQL script which connects to the above RDS instance

```
    resource "aws_instance" "my_db_sql_script_runner_instance" {
    #details
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
    #run sql script
    }
    }
```

Now I want to delete this EC2 instance automatically once the SQL script is executed (as it's a one time task). 
The code runs on CI/CD. Therefore running `terraform destroy -resource <resource>` is not possible. And I am not really open (and allowed) to change the existing CI/CD pipeline.

I was looking for something like `resource "destroy_resource" "ec2_instance_resource"` in the same terraform file. Is there any way we can acheive this?

Comment: Just kill the instance after the script has finished? Why do you need to remove it from the state?

Comment: Do you mean manually kill the instance? wouldn't it cause the drift from tf state vs actual resources?

Comment: I meant running something like `aws ec2 terminate-instances...` at the end of the script, in the remote-exec (or in a local-exec)

Comment: but I'm not sure if it would cause drift, it probably would

Comment: @Paolo that would get the terraform state out-of-sync with the infrastructure, and the next time you run Terraform the server would be recreated.

Comment: @BhushanKarmarkar What you are asking for isn't really something Terraform supports out of the box. You will have to run Terraform apply once, let the EC2 instance be created. Then remove the EC2 resource from Terraform, and run Terraform apply again to have Terraform remove the instance. There's no way to do this in a single `terraform apply`

Comment: @Mark B Thanks. On this thread, it says we can change the state of ec2 instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460706/how-to-stop-start-running-ec2-instance-via-terraform
But I am getting - The provider hashicorp/aws does not support resource type "aws_ec2_instance_state"

Comment: Your terraform AWS provider is out of date if it can't find that resource. However that resource can only stop the instance, it can't terminate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of imperative action is not something Terraform is designed to handle. Terraform is designed for long-lived infrastructure which can be changed to match what's described in the configuration over time.

Terraform is therefore not the appropriate tool for this use-case. Imperative actions like these would be better handled using imperative techniques, such as using the AWS CLI in a script or using the AWS SDK in a program you write in a programming language of your choice (assuming it has an AWS SDK available).