# How to stop instances by using terraform code?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

C:\terraform\2-instances>terraform _____________

here with out destroy just stop instance is it possible what is the code above command

Answer (score 2):

Clearly there's some missing info for this question and actually did not understand what does 'here with out destroy just stop instance is it possible what is the code above command' means.

but as for the question mentioned in the title - If you want just to stop the instance, [follow this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158310/how-to-restart-ec2-instance-using-terraform-without-destroying-them)

Or use this code (customize it for your usage)

```
resource "aws_instance" "your_instance" {
  ami           = ami
  instance_type = "type"

  tags = {
    Name = "name"
  }
}

resource "aws_ec2_instance_state" "your_instance" {
  instance_id = aws_instance.test.id
  state       = "stopped"
}
```

You can view official documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_instance_state)

If you want to delete (destroy), you can use the `terraform destroy`